# Overlay button prevents dialogs from appearing, using TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT

Tags: android

I am adding a notification icon to be overlaid in the corner of all activities when there important things the user needs to know.  I have it working, except it prevents spinners, dialogs, and EditText from working.  Spinners appear to work, except you can't see them, like if you touch it, then touch again, an option gets selected, but the spinner dialog doesn't appear.

Base Activity that other activities extend:

```
public abstract class LoggedInActivity
        extends GaugesActivity
{
    private static final String TAG = "LoggedInActivity";

    private WindowManager wm;
    private boolean overlayCreated = false;
    private LinearLayout mOverlay;
    private ImageView mOverlayImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String duplicateTruckGuid = prefs.getString("duplicateTruckGuid", "");
        if (! duplicateTruckGuid.isEmpty()){
            createOverlay();
        }
    }

    protected void createOverlay(){
        if (overlayCreated) return;

        // Create System overlay
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,  // WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.BOTTOM;
        params.token = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().getWindowToken();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mOverlay = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay_notification, null);
//        mOverlayImageView = (ImageView) mOverlay.findViewById(R.id.overlay_notification_image);

        try {
            wm.addView(mOverlay, params);

            final Context context = this;

            mOverlay.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationsActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            Log.i(TAG, e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

overlay_notification.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/black_transparent_overlay">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/overlay_notification_image"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_warning_active"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/normal_padding"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you using an `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` overlay for your own activities? Just add the `ImageView` widget to the activities.

Comment: I am using an overlay so I don't have to go edit the XML on all the activities.  It is a fairly large app, there are about 50 activities.  I am not sure TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT is the best way, its what I read from other online examples.

Comment: "I am using an overlay so I don't have to go edit the XML on all the activities" -- that is akin to saying that it is OK to hack a user's Web browser, because you don't feel like updating a bunch of Web pages on your site. Your overlay is not only interfering with *your* activities, but it will interfere with *all the activities across the device* while it is added.

Comment: I have a need for an overlay, if you don't want to help that's fine.  I have a technical question of how something in Android works and I am reaching out for help.

Comment: "I have a need for an overlay" -- not according to you, in your prior comment. "if you don't want to help that's fine" -- I am helping the others who stumble upon this question, to help them understand that what you are doing is not appropriate. Beyond that, `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` is designed to intercept touch events, and therefore it is going to tend to interfere with whatever window is beneath it (which can be a window from any application). That's one of the reasons why you need a permission to use it. If you want an image in your activities, put the image in your activities, please.

Comment: Thank you for explanation.  Is it not technically possible to programmatically add an overlay to an activity?  I also tried TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL and a couple others, but kept running into a  null application token error when doing from onCreate() or onResume(), though calling the method from a menu worked.

Comment: "Is it not technically possible to programmatically add an overlay to an activity?" -- you can add the overlay, but your choice of overlay will have an impact upon the behavior. `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` can receive touch events, and so interferes with input to the underlying foreground activity. `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` is for output but does not respond to touch events. I do not recall the role of `TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL`, though the `TYPE_APPLICATION_` overlays will at least not require the permission IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR` instead of `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`.

Also, `FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL` is already implicitly set by `FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` so you don't need to add it manually.

However, I suggest you to consider an alternative as pointed out by CommonsWare.

Comment: Thanks, this works, and I will look into programmatically adding to the activity view that is better practice. I should be able to do getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(), and then add to the layout to the activity view.